# Unable to generate grid lines

Tags: javascript, html, svg, d3.js, charts

I have been trying to obtain grid lines in my chart I have been going through d3 tips and tricks by d3noob. Help me if my code is wrong

**Style**

```
body {
    font: 12px Arial;
}
path {
    stroke: steelblue;
    stroke-width: 2;
    fill: none;
}
.axis path, .axis line {
    fill: none;
    stroke: grey;
    stroke-width: 1;
    shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}
.grid.tick {
    stroke: lightgrey;
    opacity: 0.7;
}
.grid path {
    stroke-width: 0;
}
```

**Code**

```
<body>
    <!-- load the d3.js library -->
    <script src="d3.v3.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        // Set the dimensions of the canvas / graph
        Var margin = {
            top: 30,
            right: 20,
            bottom: 30,
            left: 50
        },
        width = 400 - margin.left - margin.right,
        height = 200 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

        // Parse the date / time
        var parseDate = d3.time.format("%d-%b-%y").parse;

        // Set the ranges
        var x = d3.time.scale().range([0, width]);
        var y = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]);

        // Define the axes
        var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x)
            .orient("bottom").ticks(5);

        var yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(y)
            .orient("left").ticks(5);

        // Define the line
        var valueline = d3.svg.line()
            .interpolate("bundle")
            .x(function(d) {
            return x(d.date);
        })
            .y(function(d) {
            return y(d.close);
        });

        // Adds the svg canvas
        var svg = d3.select("body")
            .append("svg")
            .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
            .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
            .append("g")
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

        function make_x_axis() {
            return d3.svg.axis()
                .scale(x)
                .orient("bottom")
                .ticks(5)
        }

        function make_y_axis() {
            return d3.svg.axis()
                .scale(y)
                .orient("left")
                .ticks(5)
        }


        // Get the data
        d3.csv("data.csv", function(error, data) {
            data.forEach(function(d) {
                d.date = parseDate(d.date);
                d.close = +d.close;
            });

            // Scale the range of the data
            x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) {
                return d.date;
            }));
            y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) {
                return d.close;
            })]);

            // Add the valueline path.
            svg.append("path")
                .attr("class", "line")
                .attr("d", valueline(data));

            // Add the X Axis
            svg.append("g")
                .attr("class", "x axis")
                .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
                .call(xAxis);


            svg.append("text") // text label for the x axis
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + (width / 2) + " ," + (height + margin.bottom) + ")")
                .style("text-anchor", "middle")
                .text("Date");


            // Add the Y Axis
            svg.append("g")
                .attr("class", "y axis")
                .call(yAxis);

            svg.append("text")
                .attr("x", (width / 2))
                .attr("y", 0 - (margin.top / 2))
                .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
                .style("font-size", "16px")
                .style("text-decoration", "underline")
                .text("Value vs Date Graph");

            svg.append("g")
                .attr("class", "grid")
                .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
                .call(make_x_axis()
                .tickSize(-height, 0, 0)
                .tickFormat(""))

            svg.append("g")
                .attr("class", "grid")
                .call(make_y_axis()
                .tickSize(-width, 0, 0)
                .tickFormat(""))

        });
    </script>
</body>
```

**data.csv**

```
date,close
1-May-12,58.13
30-Apr-12,53.98
27-Apr-12,67.00
26-Apr-12,89.70
25-Apr-12,99.00
24-Apr-12,130.28
23-Apr-12,166.70
20-Apr-12,234.98
19-Apr-12,345.44
18-Apr-12,443.34
17-Apr-12,543.70
16-Apr-12,580.13
13-Apr-12,605.23
12-Apr-12,622.77
11-Apr-12,626.20
10-Apr-12,628.44
9-Apr-12,636.23
5-Apr-12,633.68
4-Apr-12,624.31
3-Apr-12,629.32
2-Apr-12,618.63
30-Mar-12,599.55
29-Mar-12,609.86
28-Mar-12,617.62
27-Mar-12,614.48
26-Mar-12,606.98
```

Comment: where have you declared "d3"?. Your code throws error at "var parseDate = d3.time.format("%d-%b-%y").parse;". d3 undefined

Comment: I am able to get the chart but not the gridlines

Comment: What are you doing differently than in the tutorial you're going through?

Comment: In the tutorial its a line graph. I want to generate a scatter plot.

Comment: But I was trying to obtain a similar graph as in the tutorial step by step but with grid lines code I didn't get the grid lines

Answer (score 0):

Could be the problem is caused in the first line of code, where **var** is shown as Var. See if that helps

```
Var margin = {
            top: 30,
            right: 20,
            bottom: 30,
            left: 50
        },
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a space in your CSS:

```
.grid.tick {
    stroke: lightgrey;
    opacity: 0.7;
}
```

should be

```
.grid .tick {
    stroke: lightgrey;
    opacity: 0.7;
}
```

or if you want to be more precise

```
g.grid g.tick line {
    stroke: lightgrey;
    opacity: 0.7;
}
```

The axis function creates `<g>` elements with a class "tick".  You're drawing these inside a `<g>` element with class "grid".  However, without the space the CSS selector `.grid.tick` only applies when *both* classes are on the same element.

Comment: I am still not getting the grid lines

Comment: Can you try to put together a simplified working example (on [JS Fiddle](fiddle.jshell.net) or something similar) demonstrating the problem?  There may be something else simple going on...

Comment: Copying your code into JSFiddle, with my and @FrancisHemsher's typo-corrections (and hard-coded data) works fine: http://fiddle.jshell.net/5DRtG/  Are you sure you're not getting any run-time errors on your console?

Comment: Thank you AmeliaBR. Its working now. And can you help me to map an image with this chart ?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "map an image" to the chart.  If you're really stuck on something new, create a separate question so many people will see it.